# Redirect to the page based on the chosen buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried this code but it doesn't work.
This is my Html code

```
<div class="left-container1">
    <button class="ui button "  value="right" id="answer1">yes</button>
    <button class="ui button "  value="wrong" id="answer2">no</button></div>
</div>
<div class="navigation-controllers ">
    <button onclick="displayAnswer1()"  class="ui button next " id="next" >next</button>

  </div>
```

and this my JavaScript code

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    var button2 = document.getElementById("answer2");

    function displayAnswer1() {
    if (button1.click == true){
    location.href="./2_2.html";
    
    };
    if (button2.click == true){
     location.href="./2_1.html";
    
    } ;

    
  }
```

I want when I click the next button, it will redirect to the page based on the chosen "Yes" or "No" button.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `data-attribute` like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[data-href]').forEach(el =>{
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayAnswer(el);
  }); 
});
function displayAnswer(el) {
  const link = (el.dataset.href === '1') ? './2_2.html' : './2_1.html';
  console.log(link);
  //location.href = link;  comment because here don't work.
}
```

```html
<div class="left-container1">
  <button class="ui button " value="right" data-href='1' id="answer1">yes</button>
  <button class="ui button " value="wrong" data-href='2' id="answer2">no</button>
</div>
```

And instead of use `inline event` i suggest you to learn `addEventListener`.

Reference:

- [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?retiredLocale=en)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input radio buttons for this.
Use the `.checked` property to find out which one is selected.

```js
    var button1 = document.getElementsByName("choice");
var button2 = document.getElementById("answer2");


    function displayAnswer1() {

   // console.log(button1.value);
    if (button1[0].checked){
   // location.href="./2_2.html";
   console.log("right");
    }
    else if (button1[1].checked){
     //location.href="./2_1.html";
   console.log("wrong");
    
    }

    
  }
```

```html
<div class="left-container1">
    <input type="radio" class="ui button "  value="right" id="answer1" name="choice">yes</button>
    <input type="radio" class="ui button " value="wrong" id="answer2" name="choice">no</button></div>
</div>
<div class="navigation-controllers ">
    <button onclick="displayAnswer1()"  class="ui button next " id="next" >next</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ' store ' the clicked button in a variable. And check that.

```js
let clickedButton = ''
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.my-btn')
myButtons.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function() {

  clickedButton = btn.id
})


function displayAnswer1() {

  if (clickedButton === 'answer1') {
  console.log('clicked1')
    //location.href = "./2_2.html";

  };
  if (clickedButton === 'answer2') {
    console.log('clicked2')
    //location.href = "./2_1.html";

  };


}
```

```html
<div class="left-container1">
  <button class="ui button my-btn " value="right" id="answer1">yes</button>
  <button class="ui button  my-btn " value="wrong" id="answer2">no</button>
</div>
<div class="navigation-controllers ">
  <button onclick="displayAnswer1()" class="ui button next " id="next">next</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add event listeners to the buttons. I have modified your code and attached event listeners. Please check.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("answer2");


  button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("going to page 2");
  window.location = "./2_2.html";  
  });
  button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("going to page 1");
 window.location="./2_1.html";
});
```

```html
<div class="left-container1">
    <button class="ui button "  value="right" id="answer1">yes</button>
    <button class="ui button "  value="wrong" id="answer2">no</button></div>
</div>
<div class="navigation-controllers ">
    <button onclick="displayAnswer1()"  class="ui button next " id="next" >next</button>

  </div>
```